# Bootstrap Submenu on collapse

Tags: jquery, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want a collapsed menu.. On clicking the menu I an trying to show a submenu. I am using Admin LTE template. The template is using bootstrap.

[image]

.I am able to show  a list of menu like above but dont know how to show a list of submenu.

[image]

```
 <aside class="main-sidebar">
  <section  class="sidebar" >
   <ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree" *ngFor="let data of 
 listsvalue ">
    <li   >
   <a>
 <span>{{data.value}}</span>
   <span class="pull-right-container">
      <i  class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
  </span>
  </a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </section>
```

Comment: Can you share a stackbilts

Comment: Here is the link which I am following https://github.com/mledour/angular-admin-lte/tree/master/src/app/%2Blayout/sidebar-left.. I dont know much about bootstrap

Comment: To show a subsubmenu you would have to go into the code from the template and add that functionality yourself. Personally I wouldn't suggest doing this as even for someone with solid experience it would be a chore. At that point you would probably just make your own from scratch unfortunately.